# Image resize using app engine java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I want to read a image and re size it using App Engine java.

i am not able to find how to read image from  a location and save it in app engine.

can any one help????

Answer (score 0):

You can store uploaded image to blobstore. Read following document to know how to use blobstore.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview

Then you can use image service to scale image:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/overview